# Why In PreparedStatement The value updated in one column only

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Below PreparedStatement column2 get updated, but column1 does not get updated. Please Help

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement( "UPDATE user SET column1 = ? , column2 = ?  WHERE id = ?" )

pStmt.setNull( 1, Types.NULL );
pStmt.setNull( 2, Types.NULL );
pStmt.setInt( 3, id);
int count = pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Show definition of `column1` and what database are you using?

Comment: Please provide the minimum DDL and sample data, and a [mre]. Also specify which database system and driver you're using.

Answer (score 1):

For me (Oracle) it works. But it depends, You probably need to define the type of your column when calling [setNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int))

> sqlType - the SQL type code defined in java.sql.Types

For example for `VARCHAR`:

```
pStmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It depends, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801449/difference-between-types-integer-and-types-null-in-preparedstatement-setnull-met

Comment: This depends on the database and possibly the driver. Using `Types.NULL` like the OP is doing can just work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel updated answer